# Accessing .mdb or SQL databases using javascript in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: javascript, database, browser, activex

I have been tasked with creating something that summarizes and displays information from a database (that is stored either in an SQL server or as an .mdb).  I *cannot* convince my company that we need to use an actual application for this, since I am apparently the only one  that understands Visual Basic or C#.  All of the other programmers know only HTML and Javascript, and since they're worried about making something that only one person can maintain (can't say I blame them, since I'm not looking forward to being the only person who can answer our customer's questions), these are the languages I'm limited to.
I've had a fair amount of success in creating ActiveX ADO objects for manipulating databases, but it's my understanding that this function won't work at all in browsers other than IE.  Since I'm absolutely sure that this will be their next demand of me, is anyone aware of any way to read databases (stored locally on the computer displaying the page, in a shared folder on the network, or in an SQL database on that network) in non-IE browsers?
I've found various plugins to allow these sorts of things; this might work as a last resort, but I'm really trying to avoid having to tell the customers that our app will only work if they install some random plugin.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To open .mdb databases in JavaScript, you can use: AccessDB, it's a library to work with Access databases in JavaScript:
http://accessdb.sourceforge.net/

To fire queries at a SQL-server in your network, you could probably use: HTML5Sql: http://html5sql.com/

I haven't used the latter before though.

Comment: I couldn't get AccessDB to work in firefox, and after poking through the source code, it looks like it also is relying on ActiveX objects, doing exactly what I would have been doing with ADO.  And I don't think I can rely on all our customers to be operating with HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar type of thing a while ago and also found the AccessDB JavaScript file.  From what I understand, it only works in Internet Explorer because of the way the ActiveX objects work, as you mentioned.  I would love this to work in Chrome but I have not yet been able to get it to work in Chrome.

That said, I used the js file to produce some applications that pulls data from the database very well.  I use Access to formulate the queries since the SQL is a little different. I've been able to do just about anything including crosstab queries and export the data to html tables with ease.